# How can I use fetch api in react native that have 2 parameter?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have this api

```
  http://myIP/api/soffices/{service_id}/{governorate_id}
```

and I want to fetch data from it but I cant
here is my code

```
componentDidMount(){
    let service_id = this.props.navigation.getParam('service_id');
    let governorate_id = this.props.navigation.getParam('governorate_id');
    return fetch('http://myIP/api/soffices/' + service_id + / governorate_id)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
         this.setState({
          dataSource: responseJson.data,
        }, function(){
            });
          })
  }
```

> on return :

```
<FlatList 
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          renderItem={({item}) =>
<CardSection>
 <Text>{item.office_name}</Text>
                </CardSection>
}
   />
```

> it give me this error : JSON Parse error :unrecognized token '<'

Comment: Looks like you're not getting JSON back, but HTML. Seems pretty straight-forward. During your debugging did you check the network tab and inspect the response? That's almost always the first step. Although if this is your actual JS, it's weird, because `service_id + / governorate_id` is a weird thing to concatenate to a string.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be a syntax error. Use this:

```
return fetch('http://myIP/api/soffices/' + service_id + '/' + governorate_id)
```

or

```
return fetch(`http://myIP/api/soffices/${service_id}/${governorate_id}`)
```

Attention that in the second form, we use ` and not '

Comment: i tried them its give me : "JSON Parse error : Unexpected EOF"

Comment: Tey log 'http://myIP/api/soffices/' + service_id + '/' + governorate_id and check it to be correct. If address is correct, it may relate to server. Check if your request receives in server and server send correct answer.